# How can I tell the Android Market that I'm running an updated version of Android?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, 2.3-gingerbread, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are some apps on the market incompatible with my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15814/why-are-some-apps-on-the-market-incompatible-with-my-device)

My phone (Orange San Francisco) came with Android 2.1 and has not been officially updated in the UK so I'm now running a nightly beta of Cyanogen 7 (Android 2.3.3) which works pretty well.

I'm trying to install an app from the Android Market that requires 2.2 (Froyo) and up but the Market insists that the app is incompatible with my phone and greys it out in the install dialog box.

Is it possible to either update the Market with my details (couldn't find this option in 'My Market Account' settings) or to spoof another phone/android version so that I can download apps?

Comment: Don't some apps have hardware requirements, e.g. high res screen, that your device might not meet, regardless of the OS version?

Comment: What app are you trying to install? My Samsung Spica are officially only upgradable to 2.1, but the folks at Samdroid made it possible to upgrade to 2.2, I can download 2.2 apps just fine. However, I still cannot download 2.2 apps that have hardware requirements, e.g. Flash is not available since the phone has ARM6 CPU while the Flash binary required ARM7, etc. But apps that only required 2.2 API, e.g. chrome2phone, all are shown in Market perfectly fine.

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate. It's related, sure, but the use a custom ROM with an officially unsupported OS version is key to this question.

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons why apps could be listed as incompatible with certain devices.  It could be Android version, screen size, OpenGL version, camera configuration, touch screen type.  The list goes on and on.  You could try going to Menu -> Settings -> Applicataions -> Manage Applications and force close the Market and Clear the Data.  This would cause the market to download the lastest version of the Market and rescan your phones capabilities.  If that doesn't do it then you may have to wait until 2.2 is officially supported for your device.