# Override PlayStore Application Android Minimal version requirement?

Tags: google-play-store, cyanogenmod, android-versions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I tell the Android Market that I'm running an updated version of Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7238/how-can-i-tell-the-android-market-that-im-running-an-updated-version-of-android)

In fact, I installed an higher Android version on my phone (4.0 on a ZTE Blade which normally supports 2.1).

But when I'm connecting to the market with my phone, I'm still limited to that 2.1 version and I can't even see higher version's applications while my phone now supports those...

Is there a way of overriding that version limitation or at least push it to 4.0 ??

Note ::

- I already have the google apps installed.
- I installed the moded ROM from that location :: http://www.modaco.com/topic/351670-ics-cm9-404-coldfusionx-for-the-zte-blade-rom-updated-2806/

EDIT ::

The limitation I'm facing seems linked to something else than my android firmware.
Indeed I can download that app : [https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anddoes.launcher&feature=sear‌​ch_result](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anddoes.launcher&feature=sear%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bch_result) (while it requires 4.0 firmware).

But I can't download this one : [https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=AtomicTurtleStudio.DripLite&featu‌​re=search_result](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=AtomicTurtleStudio.DripLite&featu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bre=search_result) (while it requires 2.2 firmware).

Comment: Silly question: are you sure your rom is a real ICS version and not just Eclair skinned to be ICS lookalike? use 'adb shell getprop \| grep -i version' to verify

Comment: I confirm that it's the good version :: `[ro.build.version.release]: [4.0.4]
[ro.build.version.sdk]: [15]`

Comment: There's seemingly sth. wrong. You wouldn't want to fake your api level. Different question(s): Did you restore system app data using TiBackup? Did you install an outdated Eclair version of the GApps?

Comment: Nothing's wrong, I installed the GAPPS recommended for the ICS version.. I did restaure some apps with titaniumbackup but after connecting to the market (the problem was already occuring). I think it must be linked to my phone hardware being recognized by the google market...

Comment: Well, nothing's wrong with the getprop but with market not corresponding to it. maybe just a bug with your rom? I'm out of ideas then...

Comment: My guess is that the market is smart enough to see your hardware and is basing its filters on that rather than the OS version that you've installed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question has come up before, but my search-fu is failing me.

Comment: @AlEverett: Were you thinking of this one? [How can I tell the Android Market that I'm running an updated version of Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/7238)

Comment: OP: ICS rom for the Blade is horribly broken and is suspended... http://www.modaco.com/topic/351670-ics-cm9-404-coldfusionx-for-the-zte-blade-rom-updated-2806/page__st__7520#entry1980007

Comment: Can you provide an example of an app you can't download and the message that's shown?

Comment: @t0mm13b I wouldn't say that it's horribly broken: I'm using it as a daily driver.

Comment: Here is an example of an app that I can't download because the market is considering my phone to be 2.1 while the app requirement is 2.2 and my real phone version is 4.0 :: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=AtomicTurtleStudio.DripLite&feature=search_result

Comment: I tested another app : `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anddoes.launcher&feature=search_result` and I can get it while it requires 4.0 firmware. It seems that the limitation I'm facing is linked to something else than firmware ... The app that is not available, in my case, is `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=AtomicTurtleStudio.DripLite&feature=search_result`

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is not in the software, but the hardware. You phone uses a CPU that does not support the ARMv7 instruction set that is required by many games these days.
It is more than likely that a recent update for the game dropped support for older instruction sets to improve performance or make the app smaller.

Comment: So there's no way but to buy a new phone for supporting such apps ?

Comment: That's right. The Blade was already obsolete when it came out two years ago.